# How to fix div not overlapping with section below

Tags: html, css, z-index, margin

Unable to make the white .cta-box overlap the .footer below. I can see the white box faintly below the background color. I cant seem to put the background color to the back so the cta card is overlapping.
What am i doing wrong?

```css
.cta-card {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  max-width: 50rem;
  border radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  max-width: 50rem;
  background-color: #0047AB;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-card">
  <div class="cta-card__content">
    <h2>Ready To Build Your Community?</h2>
    <a href="/"><button type="button" class="button-hero" id="cta_card_button" aria-label="Get Started For Free" aria-describedby="Get Started For Free">Get Started For Free</button></a>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/KyloBenjy/pen/qBgRBqg)

Comment: It doesn't seem that `cta-card` has a background color, so you can see through to the footer. May I ask why you want them to overlap?

Comment: It's part of the design brief.

Comment: Ok. How about the first part? Would giving `cta-card` a background color help?

Comment: Apologies for some reason i didn't see the first part. The background color on the cta-card worked perfectly! Thanks very much.